# Applying Javascript classes to generated content before it is applied to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop

I have a situation whereas I am generating content (video links) via an AJAX call in a Javascript Object. Once this content is returned from the backend, an HTML string is generated and appended to the current HTML in the DOM. 
This HTML string contains video links wrapper in a 'div'. I need to apply a new Javascript object to each of these new generated divs and have done so using the following code:

```
if(response.videos.length != 0) {   
        jQuery(response.videos).each(function(key, video) {             
            self.html += "<div class='col-md-4' data-related-video='" + video.videoId + "'>";
                self.html += '<a href="#" class="dashboard-video"></a>';
                self.html += '<div class="video-information">';
                    self.html += '<h5 class="tk-bebas-neue">' + video.videoName + '</h5>';
                    self.html += '<p>' + video.videoDesc + '</p>';
                    self.html += '<p>Equipment: ';

                    self.html += "</p>";
                    ......................................MORE CODE

                    self.html += "</div>";
                self.html += '</div>';
            self.html += "</div>";
            newRatingArrayKey.push("#" + self.relatedDiv + " div[data-related-video=" + video.videoId + "] .video-rating");
        });     
        jQuery("#" + jQuery(self.element).attr("data-related") + " .col-md-8").append(self.html);           
        jQuery(newRatingArrayKey).each(function(key, element) {
            element = jQuery(element);              
            newRatingObject[key] = new Rater(element, jQuery(element).attr("data-rel"), jQuery(element).find(".star"), jQuery(element).attr("data-user-id"));
        });

    }
```

As you can see, after I have generated the new HTML string, I add this to the DOM then loop through the new divs to apply the 'rater' class to them. My question is, is there a way to apply the 'rater' class to each new generated div before it gets applied to the DOM? It just makes me think the page may be open to error if something fails between the new content being added and the rater class being applied to the new content.
Thanks!

Comment: After adding it to DOM, immediately hide the contents and then apply and do tests before displaying it. You could use a class for that as well. That seems like the easiest solution...

Comment: The page won't be repainted before your code finishes executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to do anything to satisfy your concerns. The browser won't repaint the page until your code finishes executing, and neither would any other javascript code execute that could potentially access the DOM before you add your 'rater' classes.

If you really wanted to do what you outlined, you could use an unattached element(e.g a `$('<div/>')`) to add your content to, before transplanting it onto the active DOM.

But the really best solution would be to not concatenate strings to create DOM elements. Rather, use a DocumentFragment and the createElement api, then freely add your classes as you choose.